# Joda time interval can not be indexed through Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, indexing, jodatime, solr

I have a database table which has two colums together specifying start time and end time of an event.

I am using Hibernate to access database and retrieve and store data.

My hibernate Model class for this table looks like this.

```
public class EstateViewing implements Comparable<EstateViewing> {
    private Long id;
    private Estate estate;
    private Interval timeInterval;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "estate_viewing_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "estate_viewing_sequence", name = "estate_viewing_generator")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    protected void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Estate getEstate() {
        return estate;
    }

    public void setEstate(Estate estate) {
        this.estate = estate;
    }

    @Columns(columns = { @Column(name = "timeIntervalStart"), @Column(name = "timeIntervalEnd") })
    @Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentInterval")
    public Interval getTimeInterval() {
        return timeInterval;
    }

    public void setTimeInterval(Interval timeInterval) {
        this.timeInterval = timeInterval;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }

    @Override
    /*
     * Time not defined is conceptually thought of as an unlimited high value
     * -1 Time is earlier than other (lower value) 
     *  0 Time is equal 
     *  1 Time is later than other (higher value)
     */
    public int compareTo(EstateViewing otherViewing) {

        if (this.getTimeInterval() == null && otherViewing == null)
            return 1;

        // Not defined, so in the future at some point
        if (this.getTimeInterval() == null && (otherViewing != null && otherViewing.getTimeInterval() != null))
            return 1;

        if (this.getTimeInterval() != null && (otherViewing == null || otherViewing.getTimeInterval() == null))
            return -1;

        if (this.getTimeInterval() != null) {

            // Before
            if (this.getTimeInterval().getEnd().isBefore(otherViewing.getTimeInterval().getEnd())) {
                return -1;
            }

            if (this.getTimeInterval().getEnd().isAfter(otherViewing.getTimeInterval().getEnd())) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

But when i give solar to index this class, it does not index Joda time interval.

The way i am asking solr to index this class is

solrServer.addBean(estate);

This estate object contains List of EstateViewings objects that i have mentioned above.

Solr index other data stored in Estate object except List of EstateViewings.

i was wondering whether this is because of the Joda time interval i am using.

Could anyone help me in finding solutions for this problem.Thanx in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why Solr would have to understand Jodatime types. I think you'll have to map it to a standard type (e.g. a `long` of ticks) before feeding it to Solr.